# Failing to fetch my local API running in localhost (Amazon Cloud 9)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I have a simple flask server that returns a JSON (flask automatically do that when you return a python dict) when it receives a `GET` request to `/` endpoint.

[image: Flask server]

It's running on my `5000` port:
[image: Server is running on 5000 port]

I know it's running and reachable as I managed to request to it, and receive a valid response, using curl, twice:

[image: using curl]

Both requests are logged into the server logs as well, on second print.

I'm trying to `fetch` to my server from a html/js script as:

```js
const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
fetch( URL )
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(json=>console.log(json))
```

or

```js
const URL = "http://localhost:5000/"
fetch( URL )
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(json=>console.log(json))
```

But I get the same error twice:

1: `GET http://localhost:5000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

2: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`
[image: Errors]

I know the code itself works because I managed to fetch Githubs API:

```js
const URL = "https://api.github.com/users/nluizsoliveira"
fetch( URL )
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(json=>console.log(json))
```

[image: Fetch github API]

I'm not sure why I can't fetch to my localhost. I think it has something to do with how cloud9 deals with ports. When removing `http://localhost` from the `url`:

```js
const URL = ":5000"
fetch( URL )
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(json=>console.log(json))
```

the snippet also fails, but it seems that the request is somehow appending the url to my C9 url.

Have someone faced that situation before?
Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: removing localhost from url]

---

EDIT:
Just to clarify, i'm not running that js/html (directly) on my browser tab. I'm running it on the C9's built in browser, which is available through "preview running application":

[image]

Comment: @Phill It’s all runing in amazon cloud 9, which is the reason (i believe) it’s failing. It may have something to do with how ports are being targeted in the c9 browsers context

Comment: Your browser is not running on the [tag:cloud9] workspace; `localhost` to your browser is your computer. You need to use the external URL

Comment: Do you know how to get context to the localhost on my c9 machine? That browser tab is from c9’s preview current application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AWS Cloud 9 Preview, AWS gives you a private link like `https://12a34567b8cd9012345ef67abcd890e1.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` which gives you access to your application. To get that link click preview application and copy it from the browser tab.

Use that link in your code instead of localhost. [AWS Documentation:Preview a running application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-preview-app).

Comment: I am having the same problem, how can I use the cloud9 private link instead of the localhost?